# Why is the number of dimensions of an array always greater than or equal to two in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, octave

The documentation for ndims states that

> N = ndims(A) returns the number of dimensions in the array A. The number of dimensions is always greater than or equal to 2

Doesn't a single dimension array, i.e., a row vector mean a dimension of 1?

Comment: This is by design. Might seem misguided now, probably didn’t when MATLAB was first designed. It’s jus the way it is, they won’t (and can’t) change it.

Comment: matlab is around matrices, and a matrix got 2 dims

Comment: Originally the number of dimensions was always 2.  Somewhere around v 3.5 (2000) it was generalized to allow more.  MATLAB started as a front end to FORTRAN matrix routines.

Comment: with two indeces you can discriminate between a row (1xN) and colum (Nx1)

Answer (score 1):

If you look inside `ndims.m`, you can see

> ```
> Put simply, it is LENGTH(SIZE(X)).
> ```

Now `size` always returns a vector of length >=2, even for empty arrays (i.e. `size([])` is `[0 0]`). Why that is? Likely a design choice made by TMW long ago.

If you want to measure "actual dimensions" you might want to use:

```
function nad = nActDims(in)

if numel(in) == 1
  nad = 1;
else
  nad = sum(size(in)>1);
end
```

or some combination of the functions `isscalar`, `isvector`, `ismatrix`.